# "Copy Shortcut" doesn't always work in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Why do some of the hyperlinks (A tags) on my page consistently do nothing when I right click and pick "Copy Shortcut", but other hyperlinks on the same page work just fine? This does not happen in Chrome or Firefox, only in Internet Explorer.

An example of one that works:

```
<a id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom_idNavLinkViewAll" accesskey="3" class="ms-core-listMenu-item ms-core-listMenu-heading" href="/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"><span class="ms-splinkbutton-text">Site Contents</span></a>
```

One that does not:

```
<a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/">
    <span class="popover-trigger"></span>
    <div class="popover fade right in" style="display: none;">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
        <div class="popover-content">
            <div>
                <div class="close pull-right" type="button">×</div>
                <div>123456789-123487123kljhsdvfs09324r5h ol gdfsdlkjhq4309igfsd lkh24350-9ujhgdfs lkhfgiousdlkhdgfs09234 lhdsg0-94235r lkhjsdgf lkjsd g0349gjhfdkl.</div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <h2>What goes in here:</h2>
                    <ul  style="list-style-type: disc;margin-left: 20px;">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Click here</span></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Internet Explorer.. If the hyperlink contains more than 255 characters (hidden or not), nothing happens. See this example:

```
<a href="255-Characters">255 characters - 8901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345</a>

<a href="256-Characters">256 characters - 89012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456</a>
```